# restriction of an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to answer the following problem:

Let $F$ be a field and $n\ge 2$.

Define $\phi:GL(n,F)\to GL(n,F)$ by $\phi(g)=(g^{-1})^T$, where $T$ denotes the transpose.

Suppose that $F$ has at least four elements and $n\ge 3$. Show that the restriction of $\phi$ to $SL(n,F)$ is an outer automorphism of $SL(n,F)$.

Comment: This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419336/outer-automorphism?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the linked duplicates. See in particular [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280067/outer-automorphism-of-sln/2280339).

Comment: For the first link there is no complete and clear answer  and for the second one i didn't understand the relation. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Suppose it were inner, i.e., of the form $hgh^{-1}$ for some $h$. Now compare this with $(g^ {-1})^T$ and choose different elements $g\in SL_n(F)$ and see what you get. Also, first take $n=3$ and compute everything directly.

Comment: i think i will fall in this subject i didn't undesrtand what you mean can you please detail more

Comment: Write down some matrices $g$ in $SL(3,F)$ and compute everything!

Comment: $g=\begin{pmatrix}g_{11}&g_{12}&g_{13}\\g_{21}&g_{22}&g_{23}\\g_{31}&g_{32}&g_{33}\end{pmatrix}$ with $det g=1$

Comment: let us suppose that it were inner ie the form $hgh^{-1}$. and let us take to ellements $g_1,g_2\in G$ then $hg_1h^{-1}=(g^{-1}_1)^{T}$ and $hg_2h^{-1}=(g^{-1}_2)^{T}$ and then what should i do?

Comment: Choose specific matrices $g$, with, say, only $0$ and $1$ as coefficients. Assume always that $(g^{-1})^T=hgh^{-1}$ with the same $h$. Then you get finally a contradiction. For computation it is better to write it as $(g^{-1})^Th=hg$, so you do not have to compute an inverse.

Comment: and what about all $n\ge 3$?

Comment: what are the spesific matrix in the general cas $n\ge 3$?

Comment: Suppose it were inner, ie there exists $h\in SL(n,F)$ such that $\phi(g)=hgh^{−1}$ for all $g\in SL(n,F)$. we take then $g\in SL_n(F)$ such that $gh=hg$ and $g\neq (g^{-1})^T$ then we get a contradiction since   $\phi(g)=hgh^{−1}=g$ is different from $(g^{-1})^T$

Comment: Suppose it were inner, ie there exists $h∈SL(n,F)$such that $ϕ(g)=hgh^{−1}$ for all $g∈SL(n,F)$. we take then specific matrices $g_1,g_2 ∈SLn(F)$with only $0$ and $1$ as coefficients then we get a contradiction: $ϕ(g_1)=hg_1h^{−1}=(g_1^{-1})^T$ and $ϕ(g_2)=hg_2h^{−1}=(g_2^{-1})^T$ then $hg_1h^{−1}hg_2h^{−1}=(g_1^{-1})^T(g_2^{-1})^T$ then   $hg_1g_2h^{−1}=(g_1^{-1})^T(g_2^{-1})^T$ wich give the contadiction since we dont have the same coefficients in the lift and right side of the final equality