# inner automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to answer the following problem:

Let $F$ be a field and $n\ge 2$.

Define $\phi:GL(n,F)\to GL(n,F)$ by $\phi(g)=(g^{-1})^T$, where $T$ denotes the transpose.

Show that the restriction of $\phi$ to $SL(2,F)$ is an inner automorphism of $SL(2,F)$.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not repost the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420310/restriction-of-an-automorphism) again. You could add there $n=2$. For size $2$ a direct computation is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment. Therefore I have to write my comment as an answer.

An inner automorphism $\phi$ of a group $G$ is a map $\phi(g)=aga^{-1}$ with $a,g\in G$. In the case of $G=SL(2,F)$, can you find an $a\in SL(2,F)$ such that $(g^{-1})^{T}=aga^{-1}$by trial and error?

Comment: do you mean that the question is false?

Comment: I did not mean it is false. Have you tried some examples? For instance, what happens if $a=\left(\begin{matrix}0,-1,\\1,0\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: for this $a$ we have the equality for all $g\in G$

Answer (score 0):

On $SL(2,F)$, we have that the standard formula for the inverse of a matrix takes a simpler form since the determinant is one. On $SL(2,F)$, $\phi$ is just conjugation by the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
as you can easily check. This shows $\phi$ restricted to $SL(2,F)$ is an inner automorphism.